# Sticky Footer, but only sometimes...continued

Tags: css, stylesheet, padding, sticky-footer

OK, so now there's a new wrinkle.  The original problem I was having: [Sticky Footer, but only sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118932/sticky-footer-but-only-sometimes).  I have a scroll bar in my browser, and I can't seem to make the extra 70px margin go away...

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="headwrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menu">
       <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#" title="Link1">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Link2">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Link3">Link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Link4">Link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Link5">Link5</a></li>
       </ul>        
    </div>
    <div id="content-container">
          <div id="content">
              <h2>
                  Page heading
              </h2>
              <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect etuer adipi scing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volut. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
              </p>
              <p>
                  Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
              </p>
              <p>
                  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </p>
          </div>
          <div id="aside">
              <h3>
                  Aside heading
              </h3>
              <div class="box">
              <p>
                  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan.
              </p>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
              <p>
                  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan.
              </p>
              </div>
          </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>Footer content</p>
</div>
```

stylesheet:

```
* {margin:0}

html, body {height:100%;}

#wrapper {
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url(images/shadowborder.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:center;
    padding-bottom:70px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#headwrapper {
    position:relative;
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    -moz-background-size:auto auto;
    background-color:#003a72;
    background:url(images/bnr_rpt.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:150px;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    -moz-background-size:auto auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    background:url(images/KMIAFS_banner.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    height:150px;
}

#menu {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    border-top:5px solid #f52620;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:70px;
}


#menu ul {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif!important;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
    padding:10px 20px 6px 20px;
    background:#003a72;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    padding:15px 20px 6px 20px;
    background-color:#999;
}

#menu ul li.active a, #menu ul li.active a:hover {
     color:#CCC;
}

#content-container {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}

#content {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:610px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 0 0 30px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#content img {
    border:solid 2px #CCC;
    float:left;
    margin:14px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#content h2 {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#aside {
    float:right;
    width:290px;
    margin:0 40px 0 0px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#aside p {
    color:#CCC;
}

#aside h3 {
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

#aside .box {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#336699;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
}

#footer {
    position:relative;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    border-top:5px solid #f52620;
    background:url(images/ftr_rpt.jpg) repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-70px;
    clear:both;
}

#footer a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    padding:-5px;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color:#CCC;
}
```

So what am I missing here?
Here's the site: http://www.erisdesigns.net/Stage/McCampbellInsurance/index.html

Comment: I even tried to adhere to this comment from the example I based my footer on:

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `#wrapper{margin-bottom:-70px;position:relative;}` and remove `padding-bottom`.

Then add a `<div class="spacer"></div>` at the bottom of your wrapper and add `.spacer{height:70px;clear:both;}` to your css like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
...
stuff here
...
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <p>Footer content</p>
</div>
```

This is usually how I do it. It might not be exactly what you want but it might point you in the right direction.