# Sticky footer, but only sometimes pt. 3

Tags: css, wordpress, html, sticky-footer

Same issue as before (see [Sticky Footer, but only sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118932/sticky-footer-but-only-sometimes) and [Sticky Footer, but only sometimes...continued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119399/sticky-footer-but-only-sometimes-continued))...

I have a footer that I want to stick to the bottom of the page unless content fills the page, then I want it to get pushed down.  I've done this a dozen times with other sites, but I can't get this one to work.  Working in Wordpress.  I've checked the order of my `divs` and I've gone over the css...any help is appreciated.

The main css components:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background:url("images/shadowborder.png") repeat-y center;
    width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        min-width:980px;
    min-height:100%!important;
        margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#content {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 20px 60px 20px;
    font-size: 1.6em
}
#spacer {
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5a5fc;
    padding:3px!important;
    height:20px;
}
```

The site:

http://www.hcfmissoula.com

Answer (score 0):

The recipe I use is:

- `height: 100%` on `html`
- `min-height: 100%` and `position: relative` on `body` (with `height:100%` for ie6)
- `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` on the footer div

Maybe be tricky preventing footer from obscuring some text near the bottom though.

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ this is the one I use.  It's always been good to me...